# Calculate time in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Today I am facing a problem in my stored procedure actually I have two requirement to change in my stored procedure. That is

1. If `@PODTIME` is -60 minutes or less than `orde_.READYTIME`, then add 30 minutes to `@PODTIME`.

   Example:  `@PODTIME=11:15` and `READYTIME=12:00` then add 30 minutes to `@PODTIME` to make `PODTIME=11:45`
2. If `@PODTIME` is +60 minutes or less than `orde_.DELIVERBY`, then make `@PODTIME` three minutes earlier than `DELIVERY`.

   Example:  `@PODTIME=17:25` and `DELIVERBY=17:00` then make `PODTIME=16:57`

For this I change in my stored procedure part as

```
DECLARE @_Deliverbytime datetime
DECLARE @_PODTimeOnly time
DECLARE @_RevisedPODtime time
DECLARE @_dropdate as datetime2(7)
DECLARE @LocalVariable datetime2(7)
DECLARE @LocaldateVar date
DECLARE @MainforDropDatetime datetime2(7)
DECLARE @_ReadyTime datetime

SELECT TOP 1 
    @orderid = orderid,
    @OrdPOD = ISNULL(rcvdby, ''), 
    @_Deliverbytime = deliverby, 
    @_ReadyTime = ReadyTime 
FROM
    orde_ 
WHERE
    billgrp = @trackingnum

SET @PODTimeOnly = cast(@PODTime as time)                        
SET @_PODTimeOnly = CAST(@PODTimeOnly as time)
SET @RevisedPODtime = @PODTimeOnly                       
SET @_RevisedPODtime = @_PODTimeOnly

    SET @dropdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CAST(@PODTime as datetime),111)                        
    SET @_dropdate = CONVERT(varchar(16),@dropdate,120)                      

    DECLARE @dd varchar(255)
    DECLARE @Sc varchar(255)
    DECLARE @2nd varchar(255)
    DECLARE @REdayTimeOnly varchar(255) 
    DECLARE @revisedDeliveryTime varchar(255)
    DECLARE @_revisedDeliveryTime varchar(255)

    SET @Sc = @_ReadyTime
    SET @dd = CONVERT(varchar(5), @PODTimeOnly)
    SET @REdayTimeOnly =cast(@Sc as time)
    SET @2nd = CONVERT(varchar(5), @REdayTimeOnly)
    SET @revisedDeliveryTime = @_Deliverbytime
    SET @_revisedDeliveryTime = cast(@_Deliverbytime as time) 


    if (@PODTime > GETDATE())
        begin
           set @_RevisedPODtime = cast(GETDATE() as time)
        end                          

      else IF (@dd <= @2nd) and  (DATEDIFF(mi,@2nd,@dd) <=  -60)
        begin

            set @_RevisedPODtime = (DATEADD(MINUTE,30,@_PODTimeOnly))

        end
        else IF (DATEDIFF(mi,@_revisedDeliveryTime,@dd) <=  60)
        BEGIN
            /* This is point 2 that is working */               
        SET @_RevisedPODtime= CAST (dateadd (mi,-3,@revisedDeliveryTime) as time)

        END                     

SET @LocalVariable=  @_RevisedPODtime
SET @LocaldateVar = @_dropdate
SET @MainforDropDatetime = CONVERT(datetime,@LocaldateVar) + CONVERT(datetime,@LocalVariable)                       
END
```

In this part where I am I making a mistake for point 1? - the point 2 is working fine.

Comment: What is @REdayTimeOnly and why are you using varchar(255)?  Is that supposed to be @ReadyTimeOnly?  If so, then rename for clarity and consider using time data type as well.  Another question might be, how will you handle the days being different, i.e. what happens when POD_time is 11:45pm and ReadyTime is 12:00am?  Final question is, in your first point you say "-60 minutes or less than ReadyTime, what does -60 minutes or less mean?  Seems like you mean between 0 and 60 minutes between PODTime and ReadyTime?